# How to deal with hardcoded requests of a webapp when using path-based location blocks?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I am trying to create a reverse proxy route using [nginx-proxy](https://github.com/nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy) and docker for [OpenTripPlanner](https://docs.opentripplanner.org/en/v2.2.0) (OTP) version 1.5.0 and 2.2.0 on the same machine.

If I have a simple location block like:

```
location /otp2 {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
    }
```

The majority of calls OTP makes gets passed on to the upstream server, however the OTP web-app also has some hardcoded calls to `http://host/otp` and `http://host/images` (**not** `http://host/otp2/otp` and `http://host/otp2/images`). As they don't match an nginx location block, they fail to resolve.

How can I ensure these calls get routed to the upstream server as well?

#### What I've tried

##### Regex + rewrite

After a lot of fiddling around I settled on:

```
location ~^/(otp2|otp|images) {          
        rewrite ^(/otp2)$ $1/ permanent;
        rewrite ^/(otp2)(.*) $2 break;
        rewrite ^/(otp)(.*) /$1$2 break;
        rewrite ^/(images)(.*) $1$2 break;                                                                                                                                                                           
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
    }
```

This works, but this prevents me from running OTP version 1.5.0 next to it, as that binary *also* requests `http://host/otp` and `http://host/images`.

Additionally, every other web-app I would run on that host that would have a route to `/images` would probably be picked up by that location block.

##### Subdomain

I cannot make changes to the DNS, so (I assume) I can only do path-based location blocks, and not subdomains like `otp2.host.com` and `otp1.host.com`.

##### Separate location blocks

Per suggestion of one of the answerers I tried separate location blocks:

```
location /otp2 {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081/;
}

location /otp2/otp {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081/otp/;
}

location /otp2/images {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081/images/;
}
```

This partially works, but leaves a few unhandled OTP requests which breaks the application (the host of the form `sub1.sub2.company.country` is obfuscated in below screenshot):

[image]

Comment: This kind of reverse proxy where the paths are different are a bit more difficult to manage. You need to change the URLs in forms, refferences to JS and CSS, Location: header etc. Some of them could be dinamically generated in JS. I think it is much easier to use a subdomain for each application.

Comment: Would love to use a subdomain, but the IT servicedesk does not offer that (and does control the DNS).

Comment: The RegEx for `rewrite ^/(otp)(.*) /$1$2 break;` should be ^/(otp)([^12]*) /$1$2 break;` In this way it doesn't match with `/otp1`. I replaced `.` which means any character with `[^12]` which means any character except `1` and `2`. Try to see if it makes any difference. Another way is not to have `/otp/` at all and use only `/otp1/` `/otp2/`

Answer (score 0):

Lets use separate location block to handle the specific hardcoded requests from OTP 1.5.0 and 2.2.0, try this config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name your_host_name;

    # For OTP 1.5.0
    location /otp1 {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }

    location /otp1/otp {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/otp;
    }

    location /otp1/images {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/images;
    }

    # For OTP 2.2.0
    location /otp2 {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
    }

    location /otp2/otp {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081/otp;
    }

    location /otp2/images {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081/images;
    }

    # Additional web-apps with /images path
    location /other-web-app/images {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8082/images;
    }

    # Handle remaining OTP v2 requests
    location /otp {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081/otp;
    }

    location /images {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081/images;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that doesn't work unfortunately. If I visit `http://host/otp2` I get greeted by a message from the upstream OTP server that the path `/otp2` does not exist. By adding a trailing slash to that proxy pass directive (i.e. `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081/;`) that is fixed, but then I still have a few remaining OTP v2 requests that directly try to call `http://host/otp/etc...` and `http://host/images/etc...`. These request are not caught by the blocks `otp2/otp` and `otp2/images`: https://i.imgur.com/SgtcG5R.png (host is obfuscated).

Comment: I modified my answer, try the new code I provided

Comment: Thanks for the update, but doesn't the `/images` block catch all the images paths? So both from the OTP 1.5 as well as from OTP 2.2 (as well as any other app that tries to reach the images path)?